# Retrieving Subscriber Key from an MO message using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

We're trying to achieve the following workflow with AMPscript and MobileConnect and was wondering if someone could assist.

1. Send an Outbound message (using the Fuel REST [MessageContactSend](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sms/postMessageContactSend.html) method) with a next keyword to link to a Text Response template.

2. Use a Text Response template (using the next keyword from the Outbound message) that includes AMPScript [MSG(0) and NOUN(0) function](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_variables_for_use_with_mobile_messages/) to check the MO message for the presence of a string and sends a reply based on whether or not the string is present:

```
%%[ Var @msg  
if (Uppercase([MSG(0).NOUN(0)]) == "yes") then  
Set @msg = "Thank you for consenting to receive messages."
else
Set @msg = "Invalid response"
endif ]%%  
%%= v(@msg) =%%
```

3. Use the [MSG(O1) function](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_variables_for_use_with_mobile_messages/) (in the Text Response template) to insert a record into a Data Extension with the response:

```
%%[
SET @message = v([msg(0).nouns])
InsertData("Messages", "message", @message)
]%%
```

This is working fine, but the issue that we are having is that while we can insert the MO response and even the `mobile_number` into the Data Extension, we cannot seem to insert `_subscriberkey`. Essentially what I want to achieve is to track individual MO responses to the outbound message. The issue is that `mobile_number` may not always be unique. That is, if a mobile subscriber receives more than one message, I wan't to identify to which message they are replying to.

I'd also be OK if we could retrieve the original Outbound message using AMPscript, as I can use this to reconcile which message they are replying to.

I note that I can use the [getQueueMOHistory](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sms/getQueueMOHistory.html) API method to retrieve the complete history of the (a) outbound message, (b) the MO Response, and (c) the Text Response:

```
{
  "count": 3,
  "createDate": "2015-07-19T14:35:35.51",
  "status": "Active",
  "history": [
    {
      "type": "MT",
      "message": "Would you like to receive communications from us?",
      "date": "2015-07-19T14:35:35.51"
    },
    {
      "type": "MO",
      "message": "yes",
      "date": "2015-07-19T14:36:36.04"
    },
    {
      "type": "MT",
      "message": "Thank you for consenting to receive messages",
      "date": "2015-07-19T14:37:03.88"
    }
  ]
}
```

So there's obviously a trackable chain here, but is it possible to insert a unique identifier (`tokenId` from the [MessageContactSend](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sms/postMessageContactSend.html) method, `_subscriberkey` or other identifier) using AMPscript into a Data Extension, so I can achieve a similar tracking function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `_subscriberKey` is not available in MobileConnect context, you have to use `subscriberId`. We can get the `subscriberId` but even though there is a SubscriberKey field in [the SubscriberSMS Data View](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribersms/), that value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the `SubscriberKey` is the mobile number for SMS Subscribers.

Why not just write your own log by including an `InsertData()` function in all your messages?  Perhaps a Data Extension like this:

```
Created - default of today's date (primary key) 
Campaign  - some arbitrary, hardcoded value (primary key)
Keyword - hardcoded value (primary key) 
Mobile_Number - (primary key)
Msg
Nouns
Verb
```

This would basically give you a log of all messages and responses, which you could query as needed.

I don't know any way of explicitly tracking conversation threads for a particular mobile number.  Those conversations have always been kind of mysterious to me.